# Subnetting an network into different number of subnets

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Assuming you are using a Class C IP address (195.16.1.0) and you need to create the following numbers of subnets for your network plan. For each of the numbers of required subnets below, provide how many bits would you borrow as subnet bits and what would be the subnet mask?

1. 5 subnets
2. 3 subnets
3. 8 subnets
4. 10 subnets
5. 25 subnets

I want to know the steps of how to divide this network into these number of subnets

Comment: Network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had network address classes in this century.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Comment: Okay but this is a required question and it would be helpful if you can help me answer the question

Comment: I know how to find the prefix broadcast and everything but what I need help in is how to divide it into a specific number of subnets and how do I get the mask for that

Comment: You did not read the entire answer; it has two parts to it, and the second part completely explains what you are asking.

Comment: Take the smallest integer bigger than the  base 2 logarithm of the number of subnets: for instance lg2(5) = 2.32 so the number of bits to borrow is 3